# Why is it saying my If statement is unreachable?

Tags: java

The compiler is saying that the statement is unreachable on the line with the `if` statement. I'm not overly familiar with Java.

```
public double calculate()
{
  total_usage_charge = getUsageCharge();
  total_charge = rate + total_usage_charge;

  return total_charge;

  if("A".equals(package_plan.toUpperCase()) && getUsageCharge() > 14.95)
  {
    sB = getUsageCharge() - 14.95;
    System.out.println("You're spending more money than you should. If you switched to Plan B you would save:$" + sB);
  }
}
```

Comment: I removed the help case and other clutter. Please try to remove unneeded code to help us (and you!) focus on the actual problem.

Comment: If compiler says that some statement is unreachable means that there is no way to reach statement during the code execution. Compiler can found some cases of unreachable code during compile time (example: return before last statement, if(false) { statement }, etc.

But be careful because compiler can't find all cases because program execution path depends on previous executed statements, so you have to pay attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're returning from the method by executing this:

```
return total_charge;
```

So the next statement is never going to be executed.

Comment: Thank you for being so patient with my dumb question.

Comment: Even I used to ask dumb questions when I was fresher..:)

Answer (score 3):

You return (`return total_charge;`) from your method just before the `if` statement. No code after a `return` can ever be executed (except the relevant `finally` block if your return statement is located in a `try...catch...finally`).

Comment: It means a lot that you answered my very noobish question.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning before calling if statement so its unreacheable .

*A method returns to the code that invoked it when it reaches a return statement.*

Comment: Ohhhhhh.... Okay thanks. I'm sorry. That was probably something that was really obvious but I'm really bad at Java.

Answer (score 1):

```
return total_charge;
```

You method returns at this point, post which any code won't be reachable.

Answer (score 1):

you have putted return statement above IF. so when compiler comes on this statement everytime it returns from there and if can not executed anytime so, remove returns statement or put it below if Condition.

Answer (score 1):

Code will not be executed after return statement.following block of code is causing problem i.e.

```
return total_charge;
```

So you will have to remove this line or put it at the end.!

Answer (score 0):

```
public double calculate()
{
  total_usage_charge = getUsageCharge();
  total_charge = rate + total_usage_charge;

  if("A".equals(package_plan.toUpperCase()) && getUsageCharge() > 14.95)
  {
    sB = getUsageCharge() - 14.95;
    System.out.println("You're spending more money than you should. If you switched to Plan B you  would save:$" + sB);
  }

  return total_charge;
}
```

Just like that ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
**if("A".equals(package_plan.toUpperCase()) && getUsageCharge() > 14.95)
        {
            sB = getUsageCharge() - 14.95;
            System.out.println("You're spending more money than you should. If you switched to Plan B you would save:$" + sB);
        }
        else if("A".equals(package_plan.toUpperCase()) && getUsageCharge() > 19.95)
        {
            sC = getUsageCharge() - 19.95;
            System.out.println("You're spending more money than you should. If you switched to Plan C you would save:$" + sC);
        }
        else if("B".equals(package_plan.toUpperCase()) && hours < 10)
        {
            sA = getUsageCharge() - 9.95;
            System.out.println("You're spending more money than you should. If you switched to Plan A you would save:$" + sA);
        }
        else if("B".equals(package_plan.toUpperCase()) && getUsageCharge() > 19.95)
        {
            sC = getUsageCharge() - 19.95;
            System.out.println("You're spending more money than you should. If you switched to Plan C you would save:$" + sC);**
        }**
```

Did u meant to comment it, if yes do it right. or this is error and unreachable statement according to the code provided.

Comment it with `/* your code to comment */`

Comment: Should have been **highlighted** I guess.